# ERROR: 508 (Loop detected)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Well, this isn't like a proper question or anything..
I am just a bit curious, tried searching but couldn't find accurate answer for my problem so I had decided to try out and ask another question out here.

I have this small fun-time project in which you are supposed to keep on clicking a button until you gain the highest clicks among the other players, I have a page **ManageClick.php** which has the following code in it -

```
<?
sleep(rand(1,3));
$storage = fopen("TOTAL.txt", "r+");
if (flock($storage, LOCK_EX)) {
    $a = fread($storage,filesize("TOTAL.txt"));
    $a++;
    fseek($storage, 0);
    fwrite($storage, $a);    
    flock($storage, LOCK_UN);
} else { 
}
fclose($storage);
?>
```

The above adds a **random delay** between 1-3 seconds and then opens a file **TOTAL.txt** reads it, and adds +1 to the value in the file.

I have a main page Testpage.html which has a simple button and a JQuery function which calls the page **ManageClick.php** when the button is clicked. However, now the problem arises. Whenever an user rapidly clicks the button in the main page it shows the following error in the Console window-

```
 GET http://domain.tk/ManageClick.php 508 (Loop Detected) 
 GET http://domain.tk/TOTAL.txt 508 (Loop Detected)
```

**WHERE** domain is my website's name.

Any idea what could be causing the following issue? Rapid clicking of the button is one of them which I guess sends multiple requests to the page and causes the 508 error. Also, any possible way in which I could try and fix this error from showing up in the Console?

Also, please note that I am not English... Sorry for it.

**PLEASE SEE**- Adding the code of my Testpage.html for better quality of help.

```
 <html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
$("img").click(function() {
var test = $("#Clicks").load("TOTAL.txt");
$.post('ManageClick.php');
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body >
<center>
<img src='ABCD.png'>
<div id='Clicks' style=""></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show the Ajax code.

Comment: `GET http://domain.tk/TOTAL.txt` should not have been in the console window based on the code you've shared. Something else is going on here.

Comment: Also a cause for this can be bad ModRewrite rules.

Comment: what is in the TOTAL.txt file at the beginning of this project?

Comment: @webjuju The value of TOTAL.txt is 1 at the moment.

Comment: @DanFromGermany the code isnt much, just a small function which calls the ManageClick.php file by $.post ("ManageClick.php");

Comment: Please post your HTML code. It will help us check the button and scripts on the page for loops.

Comment: @Sub6resources Sure thing. Thou I can only post it tommorow as it is way too late over here.

Comment: **Please see**- Updated the code of my Testpage.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood, you have a webpage that has a game in which you call a php script to save how many times the user has clicked on a button.

You say the console (I guess chrome's developper tools or the similar) returns a 508 error as "Loop detected". This is the server telling the client that there might be a loop in the code because it gets called too many times. Well... it's not an automated redirect, it's just you calling it tons of times.

According to your explanation of the game, I would rather save the number of clicks in a javascript variable, and send them only after the game ended. This way, you only call the server one time.

On the other hand, your php code assumes that there's only one user of your website. I mean, you save the value in a file, but it doesn't take in account who's game is it.

Think that if you and I opened the website at the same time, you start adding clicks, and then I add another one, but the count gets saved in the same place.

## Edit: Code example

jQuery:

```
var test = $("#Clicks").load("TOTAL.txt");
$("img").click(function() {
  test = parseInt(test) + 1;
});
```

With this, you load the number previously stored and keep count of the clicks. Next you need to build a function that sends the click count after some idle time (or if you have a timeout per round )

I'll assume that if the user spent 3 seconds without clicking, he's gone, so I update the server. The new jquery would be:

```
var test = $("#Clicks").load("TOTAL.txt");
var wdt;
$("img").click(function() {
  wdt = setTimeout(serversync, 3000);
  test = parseInt(test) + 1;
});

function serversync(){
  $.post('ManageClick.php?count='+test);
}
```

In this code I added the `serversync` function. It runs after 3000 ms have gone for the `setTimeout()`. This timeout gets fired when the user clicks, but if there's a click again, the timer resets.

Finally, you should pass the new count value to the `ManageClick.php` script. I passed it as the `count` GET attribute (which you can retrieve in your php by `$_GET['count']`

Of course, this is not perfect nor safe (I could easily fake a massive count to be sent to the server, but that's another story), but it's the idea

Comment: That's like how I could make it..  The total clicks done by everyone are supposed to be stored in a separate file whose value needs to be displayed everytime the user clicks the button.. Basically it is just like a view-counter (Except that user needs to click a button to add +1 in the file)

Comment: If the user likes, he could create his own account in which the clicks done by that particular user will be stored in a table and are visible to everyone in the form of 'leaderboards' (Actually.. 40% of the website is in Hindi)

Comment: @AkshitSharma Check my edited response. I added some code example

Answer (score 1):

Your webserver is detecting a long running script based on some configuration.  I'd bet if you take out the sleep function, it would no longer detect a loop.

Also, if you are expecting the value in TOTAL.txt to increase, be sure to cast as integer.

```
$a = fread($storage,filesize("TOTAL.txt"));
$a = (integer) $a;  // cast as integer
$a++; // now you can increase it
```

To further mitigate this issue, if you must keep the lseep() function, use the following steps in your html/js:

1. click_button (call ajax)
2. disable_button (while ajax is running/php is sleeping)
3. accept_ajax_return_value (when ajax responds)
4. re-enable button (after ajax is complete and can go again)

Comment: Thanks for your help.. Unfortunately, this seems to not work for me. Please recheck my question (Added the code of my Testpage.html) which may help in further trying to fix the problem.. Thanks